# Conversion h-parameters from common emitter to common base (request source to verify)

Tags: transistors, education

I calculated the \$h_{ob}\$ parameter from h-parameters of a common emitter transistor:

$$h_{ob}=\frac {h_{oe}} {h_{ie}h_{oe}+\left(1-h_{re}\right)\left(1+h_{fe}\right)}$$

How could I verify the result? Someone knows a source which has a conversion table? Online there are only conversion in the special case \$h_{re}=h_{ie}=0\$.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. My reference is **Motorola RF DATA MANUAL** 1978 pg. 16-136 in an app-note by Roy Hejhall "RF SMALL SIGNAL DESIGN USING TWO-PORT PARAMETERS", Appendix I. Am too lazy to do the math myself. These old paper data manuals are *gold*, containing much detailed reference material from BC era (before calculators).

Comment: Hi @glen_geek, could you send me these pages in any way? I tried to find the book online, but without success. Thank you very much in advance. P.S. I need only conversion table.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi try this: http://www.slideshare.net/sadeeshkalhara/h-parameter-conversion-formulas slide 7

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Yes, Mr. Google comes thru:<br> https://cdn.macom.com/applicationnotes/AN215a.pdf